# Creating an insert for each column in one row?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table, it looks like that:

```
value | column2value | column3value | whatever
```

Now for all values in the 2nd and 3rd column I want to create an insert into another table, so afterwards, the other table should look like that:

```
value | column2value | whatever
value | column3value | whatever
```

How would I do that? Using a cursor maybe? Whats the best approach?

**Note:** I ended up solving the problem using a cursor ...

Comment: Your table definition isn't clear. Columns are not values. So what do you want to receive in resulting table? Union of `column2value` and `column3value` columns? Or what?

Comment: Does it have to be a single insert? Or can it be an insert for column2value and an insert for column3value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO another_table (field1, field2, field3) SELECT (field1, field3, field4) FROM table;
```

If you need get data from different columns use CASE
You can read here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 0):

If column2value and column3value are in same type, use this.

```
INSERT INTO SecondTable (val, val23, whatever) 
(
    SELECT value as val, column2value as val23 , whatever FROM FirstTable
    UNION
    SELECT value as val, column3value as val23 , whatever FROM FirstTable
)
```

Otherwise, its impossible.